# comp puedo traerme registros que sean de una fecha actual en adelante en sql server?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

hola tengo una duda he estado investigando un poco pero no encuentro la solucion veran tengo una tabla llamada planeaciones esa tabla tiene 2 campo fecha de inicio y fecha final , la tarea es traerme todas las planeaciones de todos los registros a partir de la fecha actual a futuras fechas y considerando que una planeacion pudo haberse hecho o inciado en una fecha menor a la actual pero termina en la fecha actual adjunto he intentado hacer algo como esto

```
SELECT * FROM Tab_QPlaneacion_SPIDER_MTY WHERE FechaInicio >= GETDATE()

SELECT * FROM Tab_QPlaneacion_SPIDER_MTY WHERE FechaFinal >= GETDATE()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me trae todos los registros a excepcion el de hoy

Comment: ¿que formato tiene `FechaInicio` y `FechaFinal` ?

Comment: ¿sabes que hace `GETDATE()`?

Comment: ok disculpa olvide poner el tipo de dato el tipo de dato , es de tipo date y si se para que sirve la funcion GETDATE()

Comment: y colocal un ejemplo de los registros que tienes en la base de datos ...

Comment: Listo adjunte una captura

Comment: ok pero NO me respondiste las dos preguntas con esa imagen...

Comment: ¿No funciona con `... WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN FechaInicio AND FechaFinal`?

Comment: hice la prueba al parecer todo bien , gracias por tu sugerencia

Comment: debería funcionarte con esto, entre parentesis un select al getdate() para que lo tome como la variable en la condición 

...WHERE fechaModificacion >= (select GETDATE())

Comment: ¿Que esperas con una planeación que empezó ayer y termina mañana? ¿tiene que aparecer en tus resultados? ¿Y una que empieza mañana y termina dentro de un mes, entraría dentro de  los resultados?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho la tarea aqui es mostrar todas las planeaciones vigentes es decir las del dia de hoy y fechas futuras , ojo como mencione en la descripcion pueden haber planeaciones que hayan iniciado en una fecha menor pero puede traermela si su fecha de finalizacion es igual a la actual

Comment: Si no te interpreté mal, quieres las planificaciones en curso y las futuras, si es así alcanzaría con hacer  `WHERE FechaFinal >= CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)`